# Java: Fonts and Pixels

Tags: java, fonts, font-size

I'm making a game and in the menu I want to display the text in the center of the screen.
Is there a way in Java to get/calculate the width of a piece of text in a specified font with specified size and style.

Martijn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`FontMetrics.stringWidth`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth(java.lang.String)) method does just that -- it will return the width in pixels for a given `String`.

One can obtain the `FontMetrics` from a [`Graphics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object by the [`getFontMetrics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getFontMetrics()) method.

For example:

```
g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 24));
int width = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth("Hello World!");

System.out.println(width);
```

The result was:

```
135
```

Comment: why is FontMetrics abstract??

Comment: FontMetrics is abstract because the result depends on the particular graphics object used.

Answer (score 1):

In the class [Font](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) you have methods such like getLineMetrics or getStringBounds that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a JLabel that is center aligned and the proper layout manager and you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Text");

frame.add(label , SwingConstants.CENTER);
```